# Add element dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to allow user to choose few things from the same list. I want to implement choice by selecting an option, and making extra choice by selecting another option from the new list with the same content.
My code:

```
<div id="leaguesList">
  <select>
    <option>NBA</option>
    <option>MLB</option>
    <option>NFL</option>
    <option>NCAAF</option>
    <option>NHL</option>
    <option>Soccer</option>
  </select>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="addLeagueSelect()">Add</button>
.
.
.
<script>
  function addLeagueSelect() {
   var list = document.getElementById("leaguesList");
   list.appendChild(list.firstChild.cloneNode(true));
  }
</script>
```

What's wrong with this code? Script works without exceptions, but new select object doesn't appear. Thank you.

Comment: Does your function run at all?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Yes. I put alert in to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list.firstChild` is not what you think it is.

It is in fact the *text node* created by the white-space between your `div`’s closing `>` and the `select`’s opening `<`. *That* is what you are cloning and appending here, and that’s why you don’t “see” anything as a result of that code.

Use some other, more reliable method of actually getting the reference to the `select` element and then cloning it, for example

```
list.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].cloneNode(true)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hhsvr9sy/

Answer (score 0):

Give some `id` to your `select` tag and Use below code.[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PWia7z893v3sjBLt9m4o?p=preview)

```
var select = document.getElementById('selectElementId');
var opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.value = ""; //some value
opt.innerHTML = ""; // innerHTML
select.appendChild(opt);
```